# How to create a static delegate from main-viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, delegates, uiviewcontroller

hope someone can help me on learning some new stuff about delegates in iOS-programming.

I have a "MainViewController" which is the first VC when the app starts. I´ve a kind of modelselection with different UIImageViews and after choosing one of them, i´m pushing a new VC. I want to handle the modelChoice with a delegate, so all other viewControllers can listen to that and act based on the users choice.

But does that mean that i have to alloc a new instance of that "MainViewController" in every VC? Whats the solution on that? How do i create (i think its called) static delegate?

Would be great to learn that..
Thanks for sharing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your MainViewController as singleton class:

```
static  MainViewController* ctrl = nil;
+(MainViewController*) sharedInstance {
   @synchronized( ctrl ) {
       if( !ctrl ) {
           ctrl = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
       }
   }

   return ctrl;
}
```

Then you can access it from any class like this: [MainViewController sharedInstance].

You can also add method to MainViewController like:

```
-(void) addListener:(NSObject<ListenerProtocol>*) listener;
```

And when you're creating other view controllers call:

```
[[MainViewController sharedInstance] addListener: newVC];
```

Comment: Hi, Max. Thanks for your fast reply. Could you please explain me whats the difference to the following singleton implemantation? [SINGLETON CLASS](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/comment-page-1/#comment-639)

Comment: Actually no difference. It is the standard way the singletons are created. This is a normal class (with ivars, properties etc.) but it has only one instance.